# How to buy United States 10-Year Bond and what is the code?

Tags: united-states, government-bonds, interactive-brokers

To trade a the Amazon stock, the code is AMZN. Is there a code for United States 10-Year Bond?

[Investment.com](https://au.investing.com/rates-bonds/u.s.-10-year-bond-yield-streaming-chart) shows `US10YT` but there is no such code in the Interactive Trader platform.

[image]

Comment: Have you contacted them, and asked?

Comment: Just making sure you are looking for a tradable security rather than a buy and hold like [Treasury Direct](https://treasurydirect.gov/indiv/products/products.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Bond Scanner within Trader Workstation:

[image: Bond Scanner within Trader Workstation]

You can search for all kinds of bonds including treasuries.

Comment: Importantly, there is not a "the 10 year bond" security, because 10-year bonds issued on different dates are not interchangeable. By contrast, common stock issued on different dates are completely interchangeable.